# woocommerce - saving selected product vaiatons

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm going to write a plugin for product option customization, where a user will be able to select option as per their requirement. After the section was over, the next step will be to proceed and save the selected product option and with the options in a single page. Once the options are saved and updated, selected options will be displayed in cart section and order section. I need some help on this, please any one can help on this.

```
function addVariations($item_id, $values){
$getContent = $_REQUEST['toppings_done'];


$varaiationMeta = serialize($getContent); 

global $woocommerce,$wpdb;  

   if(!empty($varaiationMeta))
    {
      wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id,'_custom_toppings_data',$varaiationMeta); 
    }} add_action( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'addVariations',1,2)
```

please help  me on this [image what i required for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THw62.jpg)

Comment: I can't say I understand you clearly. You have a product as 'variable' and you set variations for this product yes? Do you want to show those variations like the way on the shown image? Another alternative is that perhaps you added custom inputs which you want to be shown as in the image without `variable` product and `variations`?

Comment: I have many product customising options, where the user can select the required toppings for the selected product in a single page,  which need to update that selection into cart and order processing sections.